# USB drive not mounting in CLI mode

Tags: usb, mount, terminal, fstab

I've been trying to get my USB drive to mount without having to launch into the GUI. I'm using a raspberry pi 3b+ with raspian OS. My current fstab entry for the usb drive is

```
UUID=845-CG11 /media/datalog vfat auto,nofail,noatime,users,rw 0 0
```

This works fine when I launch into the GUI, however, I need to access this drive from a python script that will run automatically after boot. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'UUID=' instead of 'UUID-'? And are you sure the UUID is correct? Looks more like a 'LABEL' to me.

Comment: It's just a typo. In the fstab it's =

Comment: See the 2nd comment I added above.

Comment: That's the UUID. The above does mount the device in the GUI. It just doesn't work in CLI mode

Comment: Are you sure the mount in the gui is done through fstab and not through pcmanfm (which is doing that by default)?

Comment: The fstab wasn't mounting at all. The auto mount option was ticket which is why it was mounting in GUI mode. Fixed the fstab and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The fstab was correct but the UUID was wrong. It was mounting in the gui because auto mount was on. Not because of the fstab.